# How Selenium script execution happens inside a company?

Tags: jenkins, github, selenium-webdriver

1.We develop code in eclipse 
2.Integrate it with jenkins
3.Store codes on github
4.integrate jenkins and github
5. Jenkins triggers test scripts from github

Now my questions are this 
1. Where exactly the tests run in realtime on scheduled basis ? 
2. Jenkins has to run 24/7 in company server so it triggers test scripts in one of company's computer ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Jenkins run the test on either master or slave machine which you configure.

Example: [image]

2. yes.

Comment: So that machine supposed to have all the jar files to run the scripts we stored on github ??

Comment: @Ashok92 you should create Jenkins job which do a Git clone to the project for your needs. You don't necessarily need to hold all the libraries on certain Jenkins slave

Comment: Thanks mate.. If I am doing data driven testing.. I need to upload that excel doc to github right ? If I do how exactly class files locate the excel which contains the test data

Comment: Why Excel and not XML?

Comment: @Ashok92 please accept my answer if helpful. Thanks

Comment: Ya I learned to do data driven testing using excel.xlsx file using workbook class from apache POI.. I will provide sheet name.. And java iterator to iterate through rows and cells.. I can drive test data from excel sheet to test scripts